# How to handle browsers(IE) that does not allow font downloading, when using font icons?

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, embedded-fonts

Font icons are becoming more and more used. And we have also started using them a on our website, since they are a lot better in scaling for different screen resolution / zoom levels, than normal images are.

But i have noticed that some larger companies which use our website, have for some reason disabled Internet Explorer`s support for downloading fonts. One of the companies cited malware reasons for deactivating it, but enabled it again when their users started complaining to us about it.

Any recommendations for how we should attack this issue? It is not tempting to force all IE users to use normal icons just because some companies are paranoid. [Another recommendation here on StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973421/detect-if-font-download-in-ie-is-enabled) is to use a rather nasty cookie hack to detect it, but i was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Are you already using semantically useful codepoints in your icon font? It'll not fix your problem, but "they don't get the arrow pointing right we intended" is less bad if they get some arrow pointing right, or even a >,  via the installed font fallbacks.

Comment: Unfortunately no, they have logical class names, but the text used for the icon itself is not by any means logical.